# why \usepackage{tablefootnote} puts the footnote at random locations

Tags: tables, footnotes

I wanted to make a `footnote` in a table. So I used `tablefootnote` http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tablefootnote to do that as was suggested by google search since normal `\footnote` do not work inside tables.

However, it seems the actual footnote sometimes shows up at the bottom of the previous page, and sometimes it shows up at the bottom of the next page.

I'd like the footnote to show on the same page.

### Example 1, footnote shows up at bottom of previous page

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[4-10]
\section{B}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
$e$                      & 0.97774    & 0.9935      \\ \hline
semimajor axis $a$       & 300000     & 262413      \\ \hline
true anamoly $f$         & 163.76     & 176.08       \\\hline
semimajor axis $a$       & 300000     & 262413  \\ \hline
true anamoly $f$         & 163.76     & 176.08     \\\hline
$r_p$                    & 6678       & 1689
  \tablefootnote{spacecraft will hit earth on way back since $r_p<r_{earth}$} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary table for non-tangential per and post flyby the moon}
\label{tab:part_3_1_summary}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2, footnote shows up on next page

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{float}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{B}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
semimajor axis $a$       & 300000  & 262413    \\ \hline
true anamoly $f$         & 163.76   & 176.08   \\\hline
$r_p$                    & 6678 & 1689
 \tablefootnote{spacecraft will hit earth on way back since $r_p<r_{earth}$} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary table for non-tangential per and post flyby the moon}
\label{tab:part_3_1_summary}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\section{C}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Miktex 2.9, latest.

Comment: Footnotes to floats don't make sense.

Comment: Would it be OK for you if the footnote appears immediately below the table and not at the bottom of the page?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, sure. I used this package only because it was suggested to use when making footnotes in tables. But below the table will be just as good if possible.

Comment: @Nasser please see my answer below for some possibilities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Footnotes at the bottom of the page to a float will produce this undesired effect since the float might float away to another page. In case footnotes to tables (or floats, in general) are really required, it's better to use footnotes immediately after the float which can be obtained using, for example the [`threeparttable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) or [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) packages.

An exampe using `threeparttable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{B}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Summary table for non-tangential per and post flyby the moon}
\label{tab:part_3_1_summary}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
semimajor axis $a$       & 300000  & 262413    \\ \hline
true anamoly $f$         & 163.76   & 176.08   \\\hline
$r_p$                    & 6678 & 1689\tnote{1} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] spacecraft will hit earth on way back since $r_p<r_{earth}$
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\section{C}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same table using `ctable`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\lipsum[4-6]
\section{B}
\ctable[
caption = Summary table for non-tangential per and post flyby the moon.
label={tab:part_3_1_summary}
]{|l|l|l|}
{\tnote[1]{spacecraft will hit earth on way back since $r_p<r_{earth}$}}
{
\hline
semimajor axis $a$       & 300000  & 262413  \\ \hline
true anamoly $f$         & 163.76   & 176.08   \\ \hline
$r_p$ & 6678 & 1689 \\ 
\hline
}
\section{C}
\lipsum[4-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Both packages offer some customization possibilities for the note formatting; please refer to the documentation of the packages

Comment: silly niggle (having *nothing* to do with the technique recommended): "per flyby" means "every flyby".  you really want "pre".  also, table captions generally look better ragged right, to avoid over-stretched spacing.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the advice in [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina)'s answer using `threeparttable`, but I had some trouble centering the caption above my table correctly. It was anchored to the left edge of the table, but because the caption was quite long, it extended beyond the left edge of the table.

My solution was to move `\begin{threeparttable}` below the caption, before the tabular environment. This way, the caption is centered within the float and uses its full width (which may or may not be what you want). The footnote is beneath the table and extends only the full width of the table, as expected.

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Here's my long caption text that I want centered on the page.
\label{tab:simulation_parameters}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1.7in}}
\hline
Material & Index of refraction\\ 
\hline
silicon & 3.47772\\
silicon dioxide & 1.54\\
silicon nitride & 2.217\\
HSQ\tnote{a} & 1.39\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Here's my footnote.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrapping threeparttable with a table ensures other formats such as row heights remain unchanged.